# Binding keys with functions

Tags: tkinter, binding

I wanted to know how to bind any key with root window as I am only able to do it with arrow keys and rest all other keys are not working the current code is .

```
root.bind("<Right>",right_dir)   
root.bind("<Left>",left_dir)   
root.bind("<Up>",up_dir)   
root.bind("<Down>",down_dir)
```

I hope you will answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language are you using. But based on your code, it seems you are using the `tkinter` library in Python to bind keys to the root window. To bind keys other than the arrow keys, you can use the appropriate key symbol names.

You can find the key name here: [keysyms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.html)

Here's an example code to bind the "A" key:

```
from tkinter import Tk

def right_dir(event):
    print("Right")

def left_dir(event):
    print("Left")

def up_dir(event):
    print("Up")

def down_dir(event):
    print("Down")

def a_key_pressed(event):
    print("A")

root = Tk()

root.bind("<Right>", right_dir)
root.bind("<Left>", left_dir)
root.bind("<Up>", up_dir)
root.bind("<Down>", down_dir)

root.bind("<Key-a>", a_key_pressed)

root.mainloop()
```